# iphone sdk integer to network short and vice versa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, networking

Is there a way to convert an integer into a network short integer on the iphone? Also, how do I convert a network short to a host short. In c, it's htons and ntohs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're programming in C on the iPhone. You can just use those functions.

There are also the [CoreFoundation Byte-Order Utilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html).